# HtmlUnit - getTextContent()

Tags: htmlunit

I´m working whith HTMLUnit, I need get text content of a HtmlAnchor but only text no more tags html have.

```
<a class="subjectPrice" href="http://www.terra.es/?ca=28_s&amp;st=a&amp;c=4"  title="Opel Zafira Tourer 2.0 Cdti 165 Cv Excellence 5p. -12">
     <span class="old_price">32.679&euro;</span>
    24.395&euro;
```

If I execute htmlAnchor.getTextContent() it´s return 32.679€ 24.395€, but I only need 24.395€

Anybody can help me? thanks.

Comment: Only keep the text after the first space in the text content?

Answer (score 3):

Just use XPath to get the appropriate `DomText` node. It seems that `./text()` taking as a reference the HtmlAnchor should be enough.